# Public Docker image with sfdx and ant installed

Tags: salesforcedx, pipelines, bitbucket

I need a public Docker Image that has sfdx, java, ant and bash install.

I was using this docker image abhisheksaxena7/salesforcedockerimg which contains the following :

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add bash
RUN apk add openssh
RUN apk add git
RUN apk add openjdk8
RUN apk add apache-ant --update-cache \
    --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ \
    --allow-untrusted
ENV ANT_HOME /usr/share/java/apache-ant
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

I need sfdx on this image, but cannot find a public one with all these.

Does anybody have a public image to share with me containing those ?

I need to combine sfdx, git and ant command in pipelines

Comment: check this out https://hub.docker.com/r/salesforce/salesforcedx

Comment: This image provide support for sfdx cmd only and not ant , bash git etc..

Comment: I tried combining 2 images one with sfdx installed and another with java and ant installed, using services, but the pipeline is taking very long to run, i need to stop it

Comment: Why do you need ant, as you have sfdx mdapi commands ? :)

Comment: Because it is simpler to login with ant rather than sfdx. For sfdx I need to use the jwt flow for login whereas with ant i can use login + pwd + security token only. Also ant has not same restriction as sfdx . You agree it is not 100% same , isn't it :)